# Export const async function => assign the result to a const

Tags: reactjs, async-await

I am trying to store the result of an async function to a const but with no success.

The code:
Here is working ok and return the converted json

```
import pako from 'pako';

export const unzipFile = async (json_to_unzip) => {
  try {
    // fetch file with CORS enabled
    const res = await fetch(json_to_unzip, {
      mode: 'cors',
    });
    // convert to arrayBuffer for further processing
    const buf = await res.arrayBuffer();
    // and convert blob to arrayBuffer using `await blob.arrayBuffer()`
    console.log('input size: ', buf.byteLength);
    // decompress file
    const outBuf = pako.inflate(buf);
    console.log('output size: ', outBuf.byteLength);
    // convert arrayBuffer to string
    const str = new TextDecoder().decode(outBuf);
    // print json object
    const unzippedFile = JSON.parse(str);
    console.log('json object', unzippedFile[0]);
    return unzippedFile[0];
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('unable to decompress', err);
  }
};
```

From here I want to store it to a const:

```
const emissions = (async () => {
      const res = await unzipFile(emissions_json);
      return res;
    })();

const emissions = unzipFile(emissions_json).then(res => res)
```

console.log(emissions) still returns a pending promise in both cases

Comment: you can try this `const emissions = unzipfile(emissions_json).then(res => res)` it will work i guess

Comment: still pending for some reason. If i do :
const emissions = unzipfile(emissions_json).then(res => console.log(res))

I can correctly see the result, of course

Comment: I guess emissions is not in await function right? if so put in async function and do your logic in there or do your logic in here `unzipfile(emissions_json).then(emissions => {...})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

**emissions** is a promise because it holds the promise object returned from the async anonymous function. To console.log the result you can do:

```
emissions.then(res => console.log(res))
```

This happens because you are trying to manage the result of an asynchronous operation so you can not treat it as if it was a synchronous operation. With that said, to store the result to a const you need to do it inside a proper async function as you did with the await keywoard or by using a Promise.then() handler:

```
unzipFile(emissions_json).then(res => {
 //logic for using the res 
})
```